# Tomcat unable to deploy my application. It failed with the following error.

Tags: java

I have been working for a java project. I am getting the following error when I deploy the app, also the error was not consistently identified.

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The type javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
referenced from required .class files
  The import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier cannot be resolved
  The import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager cannot be resolved
  The import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory cannot be resolved
  The import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession cannot be resolved
  The import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager cannot be resolved
  The import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory cannot be resolved
  TrustManagerFactory cannot be resolved to a type
  KeyManagerFactory cannot be resolved to a type
  TrustManagerFactory cannot be resolved to a type
  TrustManagerFactory cannot be resolved
  TrustManagerFactory cannot be resolved to a type
  KeyManagerFactory cannot be resolved to a type
  KeyManagerFactory cannot be resolved
  KeyManagerFactory cannot be resolved to a type
  The type javax.net.ssl.SSLContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced  
  from required .class files
  The type javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
  referenced from required .class files
  KeyManager cannot be resolved to a type
  KeyManagerFactory cannot be resolved to a type
  TrustManager cannot be resolved to a type
  TrustManagerFactory cannot be resolved to a type
  HostnameVerifier cannot be resolved to a type
  HostnameVerifier cannot be resolved to a type
  SSLSession cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: is the class/jar that contains the class added to the buildpath? Look at http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier to see what jar you might be missing in the buildpath

Comment: the required libraries are not available. Check WEB-INF/lib if you include all needed jars.

Comment: "Unresolved compilation problems" usually means, that your code has compile errors. Check your code and fix the issues. And maybe disable your IDE (eclipse?) to automagically start a program if compile errors exist.

Comment: Isn't it pretty obvious that an attempt has been made to run Java code that has compilation errors. The OP is one lucky dude who not only got away from being downvoted but actually gained votes.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the **`jsse.jar`** file is present on your classpath. The `javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier` class is referenced by an other dependency of your project but is not available on the tomcat server.

I think the JSSE has been bundled with the JDK since 1.4